# Using EHCache with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, caching, memcached, ehcache

I have heard of .NET APIs for memcached.

Is there any equivalent for EHCache?

I am envisioning a cluster of linux machines running EHCache, serving cached objects for a farm of ASP.NET webservers. Is this practical? Can this be done without installing Java on the ASP.NET servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is the James Webster's [Ehcache.NET](https://github.com/agilewallaby/Ehcache.Net#readme) - that gives you access to ehcache server through REST API. Guys at Terracotta are promissing that .NET API for their enterprise level caching solution will be avaiable sometime soon...

I'm afraid that in order to use ehcache you will need Java on your boxes, after all it is written in Java, runs on top of JVM etc..

Answer (score 0):

This article discusses the memcached architecture in more detail: [How memcached works](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/FAQ#How_does_memcached_work?).

> Can this be done without installing
> Java on the ASP.NET servers?

**Nop**

Comment: I was asking about EHCache, not memcached. Specifically, is there a .NET API for EHCache.